# Event Drive with Haskell - error of typing and managing object state

Tags: haskell, events, monads, drive

I am trying to use an architecture of Events in Haskell based on this example (that works perfectly):
https://wiki.haskell.org/Real_World_Applications/Event_Driven_Applications

And I try to apply this code to a more complex example. The idea is mutate an object (let's say Domain) in the most natural way to do it in Haskell :

```
data Domain =
  Domain (String, World)
```

... and execute several commands to World and change it (or got a message in the first parameter of tuple).

```
With World a "class" of type:
data World = World {loc :: String, descLlocs :: [(String,String)]}  deriving (Show)
```

But when a EventLook is launched, and for example

```
dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event -> Domain
dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) = do 
                                  let msg = fst v
                                  let newWorld = snd v
                                  -- Maybe IO Action !? Is possible !?
                                  return Domain (msg, newWorld)
dmUpdate dm _ = dm
```

I got this error (that with my point of view, "Domain (msg, newWorld)", is of type: Domain, no!? (I also tried to return (msg, newWorld) without success).

```
baseEventDomainProgram.hs:30:35: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘(String, World) -> Domain’ with ‘Domain’
      Expected type: (String, World) -> Domain
        Actual type: (String, World) -> (String, World) -> Domain
    • The function ‘return’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘((String, World) -> Domain)
                    -> (String, World) -> (String, World) -> Domain’
      has only three
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: return Domain (msg, newWorld)
      In the expression:
        do let msg = fst v
           let newWorld = snd v
           return Domain (msg, newWorld)
   |
30 |                                   return Domain (msg, newWorld)
```

Therefore, my idea is just pass newWorld to compute the new state (change the data of the object).
I can add this toy example.

```
import System.IO

data Event =
    EventExit            -- User wants to exit
  | EventLook   
  | EventAdd Int         
  deriving(Eq,Show)


data World = World {loc :: String, descLlocs :: [(String,String)]}  deriving (Show)

theWorld = World {loc = "living-room", descLlocs = [("living-room","you are in the living-room. a wizard is snoring loudly on the couch.")
           ,("garden","you are in a beautiful garden. there is a well in front of you.")
           , ("attic", "you are in the attic. there is a giant welding torch in the corner.")]}

data Domain =
  Domain (String, World)


dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event -> Domain
dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) = do 
                                  let msg = fst v
                                  let newWorld = snd v
                                  -- Maybe IO Action !? 
                                  return (Domain (msg, newWorld)) 
dmUpdate dm _ = dm

uiUpdate :: Domain -> IO [Event]
uiUpdate (Domain v) = do
  putStrLn $ "WORLD> " ++ show (fst v)
  input <- read'
  if input == ":quit" then
    return [EventExit]
  else
    return [EventLook]

run :: Domain -> [Event] -> IO ()
run dm [] = do
  events <- uiUpdate dm
  run dm events

run _ (EventExit:_) =
  return ()

run dm (e:es) =
  run (dmUpdate dm e) es


read' :: IO String
read' = putStr "WORLD> "
     >> hFlush stdout
     >> getLine


main :: IO ()
main = run (Domain ("",theWorld)) []
```

Thanks in advance!

EDITED :
As pointed by @jpmarinier the code shoud return only one argument so:  "return (Domain (msg,newWorld))" should be better. So I edited the code shared with this correct sentence.

But in this case I got two errors:

```
baseEventDomainProgram.hs:31:17: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘m Domain’ with actual type ‘Domain’
    • In the expression: dm
      In an equation for ‘dmUpdate’: dmUpdate dm _ = dm
    • Relevant bindings include
        dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event -> m Domain
          (bound at baseEventDomainProgram.hs:26:1)
   |
31 | dmUpdate dm _ = dm
   |                 ^^

baseEventDomainProgram.hs:51:8: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Domain’
                  with actual type ‘m0 Domain’
    • In the first argument of ‘run’, namely ‘(dmUpdate dm e)’
      In the expression: run (dmUpdate dm e) es
      In an equation for ‘run’: run dm (e : es) = run (dmUpdate dm e) es
   |
51 |   run (dmUpdate dm e) es
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: The error message says `The function ‘return’ is applied to two arguments`. Did you try with  `return $ Domain (msg, newWorld)` or `return (Domain (msg, newWorld))` ?

Comment: Yes, in fact I tried several things, but without success (but you are right), the version with return (Domain (msg,newWorld)) should be better. Nevertheless I got this error:

Comment: baseEventDomainProgram.hs:31:17: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘m Domain’ with actual type ‘Domain’
    • In the expression: dm
      In an equation for ‘dmUpdate’: dmUpdate dm _ = dm
    • Relevant bindings include
        dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event -> m Domain
          (bound at baseEventDomainProgram.hs:26:1)
   |
31 | dmUpdate dm _ = dm
   |

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanations! You're absolutely right, I had misunderstood the "return" command, and I didn't understand why Haskell was forcing to me to use monads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you're almost done.

There is a slight change required to have the body of function `dmUpdate` agree with its type:

```
import System.IO

data Event =
    EventExit            -- User wants to exit
  | EventLook   
  | EventAdd Int         
  deriving(Eq,Show)


data World = World {loc :: String, descLlocs :: [(String,String)]}  deriving (Show)

theWorld = World {loc = "living-room",
                  descLlocs = [("living-room", "you are in the living-room. a wizard is snoring loudly on the couch.")
                , ("garden", "you are in a beautiful garden. there is a well in front of you.")
                , ("attic", "you are in the attic. there is a giant welding torch in the corner.")]}

data Domain = Domain (String, World)


-- plain version:
dmUpdate :: Domain -> Event -> Domain
dmUpdate (Domain v) (EventLook) =
      let  msg = fst v
           newWorld = snd v
      in
          (Domain (msg, newWorld)) 
dmUpdate dm _ = dm
```

Note that the `return` function is gone, as you do NOT return a monadic type here.

Alternatively, this would be the monadic version (unused in the rest of your code):

```
-- monadic version:
dmUpdateM :: Monad m => Domain -> Event -> m Domain
dmUpdateM (Domain v) (EventLook) =
    do
      let  msg      = fst v
           newWorld = snd v
      return (Domain (msg, newWorld))

dmUpdateM dm _ = return dm
```

**Side note:** in Haskell, the word *return* is rather unfortunate. I think it should be called `wrap` instead of `return`. Unlike in imperative languages, `return` is an ordinary function which plays no role in control flow. Its type is:

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

So `return`is just a component of Haskell monadic API. For example, in the context of the list monad, expression `(return 42)` evaluates to just  `[42]`.

The rest of the code compiles OK:

```
uiUpdate :: Domain -> IO [Event]
uiUpdate (Domain v) = do
  putStrLn $ "WORLD> " ++ show (fst v)
  input <- read'
  if input == ":quit" then
    return [EventExit]
  else
    return [EventLook]


run :: Domain -> [Event] -> IO ()
run dm [] = do
  events <- uiUpdate dm
  run dm events

run _ (EventExit:_) =
  return ()

run dm (e:es) =
  run (dmUpdate dm e) es


read' :: IO String
read' = putStr "WORLD> "
     >> hFlush stdout
     >> getLine


main :: IO ()
main = run (Domain ("",theWorld)) []
```

### Testing:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.8.4
$ 
$ ghc q68226112.hs  -o ./q68226112.x
Linking ./q68226112.x ...
$ 
$ ./q68226112.x
WORLD> ""
WORLD> ba
WORLD> ""
WORLD> :quit
$
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanations! You're absolutely right, I had misunderstood the "return" command, and I didn't understand why Haskell was forcing to me to use monads.